# how continue new test executinon in the same window but using new class?

Tags: testing, junit, selenium-webdriver

I have test in selenium webdriver, run it with junit in internet explorer. So I create webdriver for ie:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "IEDriverServer.exe");
        InternetExplorerDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

I need continue my test, but using another class. All actions are executed in the same windows as in first test, so I do not need create new ie driver. How can I continue test execution? I try create just new webdriver in second test like

```
InternetExplorerDriver excep1;
```

But after running first class test failes with java.lang.NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a InternetExplorerDriver, and then pass the same instance to both classes.

Since you pass the same instance, the second class will continue from the point the other stopped.

for example (I haven't run the code, so it might have errors).

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    InternetExplorerDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    Class1 class1 = new Class1(driver);
    Class2 class2 = new Class2(driver);
    class1.run();
    class2.run();
  }
}
```

Comment: I think .run() is pseudo code to represent methods in your classes that you will call.

Answer (score 0):

I find appropriate way to solve my problem using Singleton. All I need is create new class which consist my instance

```
public class Browser{


    private static InternetExplorerDriver driver;

    private void InternetExplorerDriver(){
    }

    public static InternetExplorerDriver getInstance(){
            if (driver == null){
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            }
            return driver;
    }
```

}

And put Browser.getInstance() in each place where I need driver.

Answer (score 0):

you can make the driver object as static in the main class so that all other can use the same instance.

```
public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    public static InternetExplorerDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();        

    //works as same as above example
    TestCaseClass1 tc1=new TestCaseClass1();
    TestCaseClass2 tc2=new TestCaseClass2();
    tc1.t1ExecutionMethod();
    tc2.t2ExecutionMethod();

  }
}
```

In your TestCase classes(i.e, TestCaseClass1 , TestCaseClass2 and so on ) initialize your driver as follows,

```
InternetExplorerDriver driver = MainClass.driver;
```